# PHP DOMDocument to parse xml structure with non-alphabetical characters in tags?

Tags: php, parsing, special-characters, domdocument

The XML I am trying to parse has structure similar to this - where there are colon's in te tag: `<person:type>mean</person:type>`

Can PHP DomDocument parse such a structure? The usual getElementByTagName does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of, you really want `getElementsByTagNameNS`. At the beginning of the document, you might notice something like `xmlns:person="http://foo.bar.com"`. That URL would be the first parameter of the method, 'type' would be the second.

Comment: for the longest time, i was trying to output value from the $node assigned that using print_r. Apparently the only way to output that is via ->item(0)->nodeValue - somehow the value does not show in print_r